# Can API Key and JWT Token be used in the same .Net 6 WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jwt, .net-6.0, api-key

I am building a new .Net 6 WebAPI that will be consumed by many applications so I need to implement API Keys to limit access to only those applications. Only a very small amount of the individual users will require authorization (admins) so I would like to combine with JWT for the Admin endpoints. We do not want to require users to have to crate an account where not necessary (non-admins). Is this possible? Thank You.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
The solution I recommend is to setup multiple authentication methods in asp.net core 6 using two authentication schemes that you have to specify inside `Authorize` attribute.
Here a simple implementation of ApiKey authentication:

```cs
namespace MyAuthentication;

public class ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions>
{
    private enum AuthenticationFailureReason
    {
        NONE = 0,
        API_KEY_HEADER_NOT_PROVIDED,
        API_KEY_HEADER_VALUE_NULL,
        API_KEY_INVALID
    }

    private readonly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger _logger;

    private AuthenticationFailureReason _failureReason = AuthenticationFailureReason.NONE;

    public ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions> options,
                                       ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
                                       ILogger<ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler> logger,
                                       UrlEncoder encoder,
                                       ISystemClock clock) : base(options, loggerFactory, encoder, clock)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        //ApiKey header get
        if (!TryGetApiKeyHeader(out string providedApiKey, out AuthenticateResult authenticateResult))
        {
            return authenticateResult;
        }

        //TODO: you apikey validity check
        if (await ApiKeyCheckAsync(providedApiKey))
        {
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal();  //TODO: Create your Identity retreiving claims
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.Scheme);

            return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
        }

        _failureReason = AuthenticationFailureReason.API_KEY_INVALID;
        return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
    }

    protected override async Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        //Create response
        Response.Headers.Append(HeaderNames.WWWAuthenticate, $@"Authorization realm=""{ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme}""");
        Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
        Response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Json;

        //TODO: setup a response to provide additional information if you want
        var result = new
        {
            StatusCode = Response.StatusCode,
            Message = _failureReason switch
            {
                AuthenticationFailureReason.API_KEY_HEADER_NOT_PROVIDED => "ApiKey not provided",
                AuthenticationFailureReason.API_KEY_HEADER_VALUE_NULL => "ApiKey value is null",
                AuthenticationFailureReason.NONE or AuthenticationFailureReason.API_KEY_INVALID or _ => "ApiKey is not valid"
            }
        };

        using var responseStream = new MemoryStream();
        await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(responseStream, result);
        await Response.BodyWriter.WriteAsync(responseStream.ToArray());
    }

    protected override async Task HandleForbiddenAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        //Create response
        Response.Headers.Append(HeaderNames.WWWAuthenticate, $@"Authorization realm=""{ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme}""");
        Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
        Response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Json;

        var result = new
        {
            StatusCode = Response.StatusCode,
            Message = "Forbidden"
        };

        using var responseStream = new MemoryStream();
        await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(responseStream, result);
        await Response.BodyWriter.WriteAsync(responseStream.ToArray());
    }

    #region Privates
    private bool TryGetApiKeyHeader(out string apiKeyHeaderValue, out AuthenticateResult result)
    {
        apiKeyHeaderValue = null;
        if (!Request.Headers.TryGetValue("X-Api-Key", out var apiKeyHeaderValues))
        {
            _logger.LogError("ApiKey header not provided");

            _failureReason = AuthenticationFailureReason.API_KEY_HEADER_NOT_PROVIDED;
            result = AuthenticateResult.Fail("ApiKey header not provided");

            return false;
        }

        apiKeyHeaderValue = apiKeyHeaderValues.FirstOrDefault();
        if (apiKeyHeaderValues.Count == 0 || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(apiKeyHeaderValue))
        {
            _logger.LogError("ApiKey header value null");

            _failureReason = AuthenticationFailureReason.API_KEY_HEADER_VALUE_NULL;
            result = AuthenticateResult.Fail("ApiKey header value null");

            return false;
        }

        result = null;
        return true;
    }

    private Task<bool> ApiKeyCheckAsync(string apiKey)
    {
        //TODO: setup your validation code...

        return Task.FromResult<bool>(true);
    }
    #endregion
}

public class ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
{
    public const string DefaultScheme = "ApiKey";

    public static string Scheme => DefaultScheme;
    public static string AuthenticationType => DefaultScheme;
}

public static class AuthenticationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddApiKeySupport(this AuthenticationBuilder authenticationBuilder, Action<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions> options)
        => authenticationBuilder.AddScheme<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions, ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler>(ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme, options);
}
```

Then register inside builder setup:

```cs
_ = services.AddAuthentication(options =>
             {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme;
             })
             .AddApiKeySupport(options => { });
```

You have to also setup the standard JWT Bearer validation (I don't post it for the sake of brevity).

To protect your endpoint add the `Authorize` attribute like:

```cs
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme)]  //ApiKey
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
   //...omissis...

   return null;
}

//or..

[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] //Jwt
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
   //...omissis...

   return null;
}

//or..
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = $"{JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme},{ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme}" )] //ApiKey and Jwt
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
   //...omissis...

   return null;
}
```

For me it is the best way so as to carry out the authorization check before the start of the application pipeline (fail fast) and to be able to create the user identity.

But if you don't need to put informations about the Api Key inside the `ClaimsPrincipal` and only check the validity of Api Key the simplest way to do that is:

- Protect the "admin" actions with JWT auth (with `Authorize` attribute)
- Setup and register a middleware to only check the Api Key in all actions
  Here is an example:

```cs
public class SimpleApiKeyMiddleware
{
    private static readonly string API_KEY_HEADER = "X-Api-Key";

    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<SimpleApiKeyMiddleware> _logger;

    public SimpleApiKeyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<SimpleApiKeyMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        //Get apikey header
        if (!httpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(API_KEY_HEADER, out var apiKey))
        {
            _logger.LogError("ApiKey not found inside request headers");

            //Error and exit from asp.net core pipeline
            await GenerateForbiddenResponse(httpContext, "ApiKey not found inside request headers");
        }
        else if (!await ApiKeyCheckAsync(apiKey))
        {
            _logger.LogError("ApiKey is not valid: {ApiKey}", apiKey);

            //Error and exit from asp.net core pipeline
            await GenerateForbiddenResponse(httpContext, "ApiKey not valid");
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("ApiKey validated: {ApiKey}", apiKey);

            //Proceed with pipeline
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }

    private Task<bool> ApiKeyCheckAsync(string apiKey)
    {
        //TODO: setup your validation code...

        return Task.FromResult<bool>(true);
    }

    private async Task GenerateForbiddenResponse(HttpContext context, string message)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
        context.Response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Json;

        using var responseStream = new MemoryStream();
        await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(responseStream, new
        {
            Status = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden,
            Message = message
        });

        await context.Response.BodyWriter.WriteAsync(responseStream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Registration:

```cs
_ = app.UseMiddleware<ApiKeyMiddleware>();  //Register as first middleware to avoid other middleware execution before api key check
```

Usage:

```cs
//Admin: Jwt and Api Key check
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] //Jwt and Api Key
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAdminApi()
{
   //...omissis...
}

//Non Admin: Api Key check only
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyNonAdminApi()
{
   //...omissis...
}
```

Note: the middleware code above forces exit from pipeline returning an http result so as to stop next middleware execution. Also note that the asp.net core 6 pipeline executes `Authorization` first and then all the registered middlewares.

Comment: Thank you ale91 this looks very interesting and it most likely works just fine. But it may be missing the point a little. I would like to add the API Key check in the middleware so that anything in the entire API requires a correct API Key. I would also like to add JWT validation only on specific endpoint - like admin functions.

Comment: excuse the misunderstanding, you can implement it by using `Authorization` attribute with multiple auth schemes decorating the actions according to the authentications to be used. Note that in the main asp.net pipeline the authorization is done before middlewares run so as to protect the execution of your code, but if you want to use the middleware I will post an update to my answer to show you how to do it.

Comment: Thank you. I know how to implement API Keys in the middleware I just wanted to know if the combination of that and also using an attribute for JWT on specific endpoints in combination was possible or is there a better solution.

Comment: @JimEvans It's possible, just keep in mind that middleware registration order is important  and to exit from "ApiKey" middleware if errors occurs (you don't have to call `await _next(httpContext);`) so as to stop the middleware pipeline.

Comment: @ale91Thank you again and yes I would want the APIKey check to happen first as that would be required for any request and the JWT only required for specific requests at the controller method (end point) level. If you want to put al you comments in your answer above I will mark it as the answer. Thank you again for all the info.